# peerjs - closing connection to specific peer id without destroying the peer connection

Tags: javascript, node.js, webrtc, peerjs

im trying to write a random p2p video chat app , 2 online users are selected randomly and they start to chat (with option to invite a friend so it might be 3 person in the chat total ) ... i want them to be able to skip their partner and chat with another random user instead  if they want

here is the simplified version of my code

```
var OURSTRAM ;
const CurrentPeers = [] ;
var peer ;

io = io.connect();

// chat starts when users clicks the   #start-chat button we add our stream and get our peer connection 

$(document).on('click' , '#start-chat' , function(){
        navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia({ video : true , audio : true })
        .then((stream) => {

            var ourVideArea = $('#our-video')[0];
            ourVideArea.srcObject = stream ;
            ourVideArea.play();
            
            OURSTRAM = stream ;
            init_peer();


        })
        .catch( (e)=>{
            console.log('error2' , e );
        });
})

// starting peer connection and sending our peer id to signaling server 

function init_peer(){

    peer = new Peer({
         config: {'iceServers': 'iceServersList' }
    });

    peer.on('open', function(id) {
        io.emit('ready' , {  peer_id : id });
    });

    peer.on('call' , function (call) {

        call.answer(OURSTRAM);
        call.on('stream' , function(remoteStream){
            addRemoteVideo(remoteStream , call.peer , 'oncall');
        })
    })

}

// reciving peer_id of remote user from signaling server 

io.on('incoming_chat' , function(data){
    callPeer(data.peer_id);
})


function callPeer( id )
{

    let  call = peer.call(id , OURSTRAM);
    call.on('stream' , function(remoteStream) {
        addRemoteVideo(remoteStream , id , 'callPeer');
    });

}

function addRemoteVideo(stream , peer_id  , caller ){

    if(CurrentPeers.includes(peer_id))
    {
      return  ;
    }
    
    CurrentPeers.push(peer_id);
    let remoteVideArea = $('#their-video')[0];
    remoteVideArea.srcObject = stream ;
    remoteVideArea.play();

}
```

so here is the problem , when users press the skip chat button and basically wants to chat with another online user instead of the current one i'll send this info to the server

```
$(document).on('click' , '#skip-chat-btn' , function (){
    io.emit('chat_skip');
})
```

server will emit to both parties that the chat is over , both users will receive `remove_peer` from server with the peer_id of the other user

```
io.on('remove_peer' , function(data){

    console.log(`removing peer ${data.remote_peer_id}`);
})
```

and they will receive a different user peer_id  (new `incoming_chat` event )

im very new to peerjs and webrtc in general , but i assume somehow i need to close the peer connection between these two users ... the current code will automatically add the new incoming user to the chat that's not a problem ... i joust dont know how to remove the current peer

there is a `peer.destroy()` method in the documentation

but it seems to be destroying the peer connection all together , which is not good cuz i need the peer connection for the next incoming chat also i dont want to lose the connectoin to the 3rd person (invited guest) , i just need to remove a specific peer_id from my connection something like

```
peer.closeRemotePeer( remote_peer_id)
```

in order to stop the current connection from wasting resources and bandwidth   , or maybe it's not important and just removing their stream and adding new user stream would be ok (which i doubt ) ... maybe i need to generate new peer connection all together after each chat is ending ?

im very lost and any help is appreciated

Comment: **ending the chat** between 2 specific persons to then start a **new chat** would be a separate connection or.. a separate `Peer`.. so maybe do something like `io.on('remove_peer' , function(data){ /*some-code*/;init_peer(); })` so that the variable `peer` would point to the **new** peer connection

Comment: You can suggest to other users that one of the partners has closed the connection and left; but, there is nothing to be done to close the peer_id as it cannot be reused. Just add a flag indicating that the peer_id is closed.